# Em um menu de 3 níveis, como setar um tempo quando o evento é mouseout no segundo níveil para o terceiro?

Tags: jquery, menu

Tenho um menu com 3 níveis na vertical(parecido com o da globo.com), meu problema é quando eu 
estou no último item do 2º nível(por exemplo) e movo o mouse para o 1ª item do 3ª nível, o
evento de hover no 2ª nível é ativado e eu perco a navegação não conseguindo chegar no 3ª
nível.

Preciso de uma solução parecida com a da globo, quando estou no 2º nível e vou para
o 3º, preciso definir um tempo para que chegue ao 3ª nível.

Meu script atual está assim:

```
//manipula primeiro e segundo nivel
    $("#main-menu ul > li.mn-item-li").mouseenter(function (e) {
        var currentMenu = $(this);

        if (currentMenu.hasClass('sub-menu')) {
            currentMenu.find('.mn-item-a').addClass('active');
        }

        currentMenu.children('div').stop().show();

        //seta item do menu mais-visto aberto como padrão            
        currentMenu.find('.second-nivel').find('li').eq(0).find('a').addClass('active');
        $(".mn-maisvistos").css({ "visibility": "visible", "opacity": "1" });

        //seta altura do subnivel
        var heightSubnivel = currentMenu.find('.second-nivel').height();
        var widthtSubnivel = currentMenu.find('.second-nivel').width();
        currentMenu.find('.second-nivel').css({ 'height': heightSubnivel + 'px' });
        currentMenu.find('.third-nivel').css({ 'height': heightSubnivel + 'px' });

        //manipula segundo e terceiro nivel
        var timer;
        var teste = function () {

            currentMenu.find('.second-nivel > li a').mouseenter(function () {
                var dataSubNivel = $(this).data("menu-id");
                var indexSubNivel = $(this).parent().index();

                $('.second-nivel > li a').removeClass('active');

                if ($(this).parent().hasClass("subnivel")) {

                    //console.info(indexSubNivel)

                    $('.third-nivel > li').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    $(this).parents('.second-nivel').next().find("." + dataSubNivel).css({ 'visibility': 'visible', 'opacity': '1' });
                    $(this).addClass('active');

                } else {

                    $('.third-nivel > li').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    $(this).css("background-image", "none");
                }
                clearTimeout(timer);
            })
        }

        currentMenu.find('.second-nivel > li a').mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).off('mouseenter');
            timer = setTimeout(function () { teste() }, 500);
        });

        currentMenu.find('.second-nivel > li a').mousemove(function (event) {
            var pageCoords = "( " + event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY + " )";
            var clientCoords = "( " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY + " )";
            console.info("( event.pageX, event.pageY ) : " + pageCoords);               
        });

    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('.third-nivel > li').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden', 'opacity': '0' });
        $(this).find('.second-nivel li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).children("div").stop().hide();
        $(this).find('.mn-item-a').removeClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: Bem vindo! É possivel para juntar o HTML para podermos testar com o seu código? idealmente fazendo um jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow, por favor, utilize o jsfiddle.net e coloque seu código html e javascript nele para que possamos usa-lo para resolver seu problema, caso você não saiba utilizar o jsFiddle, apenas edite sua questão e poste seu código HTML nela.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de criar um menu por si próprio - e porque já está usando jQuery - prefira usar um plugin que já faça isso por você:

Plugins geralmente são testados, tem mecanismos para evitar problemas como esse e incluem recursos como por exemplo suporte a dispositivos móveis.

Há o plugin do [Bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#dropdowns), que usa a sua ideia de um tempo, e o [jQuery-menu-aim](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim) que usa outra estratégia para evitar esse problema.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de usar a `.css()` você poderia usar o `.animate()`, assim você conseguiria controlar o tempo que a animação demoraria para acontecer.

```
currentMenu.find('.second-nivel').animate({ height: heightSubnivel }, 500);
currentMenu.find('.third-nivel').animate({ height: heightSubnivel }, 500);
```

Além de poder controlar a animação que cada item irá fazer para abrir e fechar, você ainda poderá controlar o tempo que isso demorará.
Qualquer dúvida veja a [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 0):

Seria bom ver o HTML relevante ao seu problema pra entender por que, por exemplo, você julgou necessário "setar a altura do subnível". Mas, de modo bem geral, o tipo de menu que você quer fazer não requer jQuery.

Usando apenas a pseudoclasse `hover` do CSS, é possível criar um menu de três níveis parecido com o da Globo.com. Fiz um exemplo bem simples, não me dei ao trabalho de deixar bonito, mas espero que a ideia esteja clara: http://jsfiddle.net/AGzUL/

O truque foi usar `position: absolute` pra deixar uma DIV aparecer em cima da outra "naturalmente". O uso da classe `ativo` permite que uma das DIVs já venha aberta junto com o segundo nível do menu. Não é o ideal e não funciona em todos os casos, mas deixei assim em nome da simplicidade.